# Remove Loudness Equalisation windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card

I have a realtek intergrated sound card on my laptop , running the latest driver version.
I experience loudness equalisation (The bass seems to quiet down even when I crank up the volume)
there was a time when this never happened.
not sure what changed. The loudness equalisation is really bad since it caps off somee good bass hits on my headphones.

How can I remove this effect, some reg hack or something.
Plus I have checked the playback options tab: the enhancements tab is missing + the telephone call setting is set to do nothing.

I have also tried the default High Definition Audio device, the loudness equalisation is much worse.
I have used loudness equalisation to describe the effect above but I might not be entirely sure i am using the right term, might be audio compression.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Loudness Equalisation is in the Properties of **each** specific capable output device in the Sound control panel...

[image]

You may need to switch it off for all your potential output types.
I would also disable bass management if you have no separate sub for that device.